# JAVA - ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm learning java and I have a exercise make a simple shop manager
Here is my ProductManager class

```
private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private String name;
private float price;
private int quantity;
public ProductManager() {

}

public void addProduct(ArrayList<Product> pr) {
    Product p = new Product();
    System.out.println("Enter Name of Product :");
    p.setName(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter Price of Product :");
    p.setPrice(sc.nextFloat());
    System.out.println("Enter Quantity of Product :");
    p.setQuantity(sc.nextInt());
    pr.add(p);
    System.out.println("Success!");


}


public void listProduct(ArrayList<Product> pr) {
    System.out.println("LIST ALL PRODUCT");
    Product p;
    for (int i = 0; i < pr.size(); i++) {
        p = (Product) pr.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
    System.out.println(pr.size());
}
```

Here is Shop class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();
    System.out.println("SHOP MANAGER");
    System.out.println("1.Product Manager");
    System.out.println("2.Sale Orders Manager");
    System.out.println("3.Save Products To File");
    System.out.println("4.Load Products from file");
    int s;
    System.out.println("Enter Your Choice :");
    s = sc.nextInt();
    switch (s) {
        case 1:

            System.out.println("Product Manager");
            System.out.println("1.Add Product");
            System.out.println("2.Edit Product");
            System.out.println("3.Remove Product");
            System.out.println("4.List All Product");
            System.out.println("5.Main Menu");
            int select;
            select = sc.nextInt();
            switch (select) {
                case 1:
                    sc.nextLine();
                    pm.addProduct(products);
                    main(null);
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    pm.listProduct(products);
                    main(null);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Shop.main(null);
                    break;
            }

            break;
    }
}
    }
```

I've created a products arraylist in shop class,but when I do addProduct,it not working,size of products still is 0. where I was wrong?

Comment: You can't just copy-paste your homework here, you should try something by your own and ask for a specific problem!

Comment: why are you trying to call `main(null)`?

Comment: tks,I realized it, I got a stupid mistake

Comment: look at @Eran answer or make your `List` as a class variable, not a local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a loop in the main-method instead of invoking it newly every time (as Eran said!).

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        ProductManager pm = new ProductManager();
        System.out.println("SHOP MANAGER");
        System.out.println("1.Product Manager");
        System.out.println("2.Sale Orders Manager");
        System.out.println("3.Save Products To File");
        System.out.println("4.Load Products from file");
        System.out.println("5.To exit the program"); // <-- added
        int s;
        System.out.println("Enter Your Choice :");

        while (s = sc.nextInt() != 5) {
            switch (s) {
            case 1:

                System.out.println("Product Manager");
                System.out.println("1.Add Product");
                System.out.println("2.Edit Product");
                System.out.println("3.Remove Product");
                System.out.println("4.List All Product");
                System.out.println("5.Main Menu");
                int select;
                select = sc.nextInt();
                switch (select) {
                case 1:
                    sc.nextLine();
                    pm.addProduct(products);
                    // main(null);
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    pm.listProduct(products);
                    // main(null);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    // Shop.main(null);
                    break;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The user wanted to exit the program!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you are calling `main(null)`, a new empty `ArrayList` is created. Therefore the `products` list of the current `main` method is always empty.

You shouldn't make that call. Use a while loop if you want your code to be executed multiple times.

Comment: thank you so much, I got a stupid mistake